# Pandas Series to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I have an object `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` that looks like this:

```
DataFrame(cfd_appr).transpose().sum(axis=1)
2022.12.06_Bild 2.txt     524.0
2022.12.06_Bild 3.txt     620.0
2022.12.06_Bild 4.txt     535.0
2022.12.06_Bild 5.txt     799.0
2022.12.06_Bild 6.txt    1032.0
2022.12.06_Bild 8.txt       4.0
dtype: float64
```

Created by `DataFrame(some_cfd).transpose().sum(axis=1)`. Now I need to transform it so it would look as follows:

```
                              1
2022.12.06_Bild 2.txt     524.0
2022.12.06_Bild 3.txt     620.0
2022.12.06_Bild 4.txt     535.0
2022.12.06_Bild 5.txt     799.0
2022.12.06_Bild 6.txt    1032.0
2022.12.06_Bild 8.txt       4.0
```

After hours of reading [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) I still can't figure out how to do that. It should be a `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` with a single-level indexing. Each time is use `reset_index()` it created some new (index?) column, and using `set_index('index')` creates a two-level column indexing that I don't need.

I can imagine there area many corresponding cases, so sorry in advance if it already was answered somewhere, but so far I have not find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(cfd_appr).transpose().sum(axis=1).to_frame(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) can be used to convert a `Series` to `DataFrame`.

```
series = DataFrame(some_cfd).transpose().sum(axis=1)

# The provided name (1) will substitute for the series name
df = series.to_frame(1)
```

And the output should be:

```
>>> print(df)

                              1
2022.12.06_Bild 2.txt     524.0
2022.12.06_Bild 3.txt     620.0
2022.12.06_Bild 4.txt     535.0
2022.12.06_Bild 5.txt     799.0
2022.12.06_Bild 6.txt    1032.0
2022.12.06_Bild 8.txt       4.0
```